# Running into a type issue trying to set UILabel into UISegmentedControl item

Tags: ios, swift, label, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UILabel` that is generic and I will pass data into it from another controller. I want have it so that the label will be the text for the `UISegmentedControl`, however I get the error that 'Instance member 'lessonLabel' cannot be used on type `LearnTopicHeaderView` (My class that is a `UICollectionReusableView`).

```
import UIKit

class LearnTopicHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

let lessonLabel = UILabel(text: "X Lessons", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 14))

let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Overview", lessonLabel, "Apply"]) // Here is the error.
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.layer.cornerRadius = 27
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedIndex), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()

}
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The `items` that are passed to the [`UISegmentedControl` initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618569-init) can be strings or `UIImage` instances. You can't pass a `UILabel` instance.

Comment: Right, I was reading that it can only be NSString. Is there some way to convert UILabel or its text property to NSString?

Comment: If your intention is that the segmented control will automatically reflect the text of the label when that label changes, then no.  If you just want the static text "X lessons" then just assign that string.

Comment: The lessonLabel is going to have data passed from another controller that it might say 8 Lessons or 5 Lessons, that was my intention you are correct. Is there any sort of workaround that the segmented control can reflect dynamically updated labels? Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: No, you just need to call [`setTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618556-settitle) when you want to change the text

Comment: Thanks this definitely is what I needed. However, I'm using it and it is showing the "X Lessons" only instead of what is passed in. The regular UILabel on the view (same lessonLabel label) reflects the data passed in. Is there a certain time I'm supposed to call setTitle, or refresh the data?

Comment: You should call setTitle at the same time as you set the text on the label

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks man, hope you have a wonderful night.